# How to wrap Wordpress wpautop in a container with a class for CSS manipulation

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a shortcode that queries through Worpress posts by category name and displays them on the front end. If there are no posts in that category, the user can write a "no posts available" message.

The wpautop wraps the message with `<p>...</p>`.

I want to style this `<p>`. I can't simply just add CSS to the paragraph tag obviously. It's not that simple. The styling needs to be isolated to this message only. So, can someone help me modify this code below to wrap the return in a `div` container with a class?

Thanks

```
$listing = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'display_posts_shortcode_args', $args, $original_atts ) );
if ( ! $listing->have_posts() ) {
    /**
     * Filter content to display if no posts match the current query.
     *
     */
    return apply_filters( 'display_posts_shortcode_no_results', wpautop( $no_posts_message ) );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a below sample :p

```php
$page_cont      =   wpautop('YOUR_CONTENT');
$added_class    =   str_replace('<p>', '<p class="text-center">', $page_cont);
echo $added_class;
```

Comment: Please post some explanation to code along with your answer. Thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by creating alternative function for wpautop().

wpautop() function is coded in wp-includes/formatting.php, copy the function to the functions.php in your template directory and edit.

1) Change the function name and add a new parameter for class name,

```
function wpautop( $pee, $br = true ) {
```

as

```
function wpautopNew( $pee, $className = null, $br = true ) {
```

2) Search and change this loop in the function

```
// Rebuild the content as a string, wrapping every bit with a <p>.
foreach ( $pees as $tinkle ) {
    $pee .= '<p>'. trim($tinkle, "\n") . "</p>\n";
}
```

as this

```
// Rebuild the content as a string, wrapping every bit with a <p>.
foreach ( $pees as $tinkle ) {
    $pee .= '<div class="'.$className.'"><p>' . trim($tinkle, "\n") . "</p></div>\n";
}
```

3) Use the new function and give a class name as second argument.

```
wpautopNew( $no_posts_message, 'yourclassname' )
```

Comment: While this code may solve the problem, it does not answer the question which is wrapping the output in a container to use CSS manipulation on the result.